# Cannot access $eip no matter the size of the buffer - gdb

Tags: c, security, gdb, buffer-overflow

I have the following C file, vuln.c, and I am trying to carry on a buffer overflow attack. My aim is set the `$eip` to the address of the function read_secret.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void read_secret() {
    FILE *fptr = fopen("/task2/secret.txt", "r");
    char secret[1024];
    fscanf(fptr, "%512s", secret);
    printf("Well done!\nThere you go, a wee reward: %s\n", secret);
    exit(0);
}

int fib(int n)
{
   if ( n == 0 )
      return 0;
   else if ( n == 1 )
      return 1;
   else
      return ( fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) );
} 

void vuln(char *name)
{
    int n = 20;
    char buf[1024];
    int f[n];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
      f[i] = fib(i);
    }
    strcpy(buf, name);
    printf("Welcome %s!\n", buf);
    for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
      printf("By the way, the %dth Fibonacci number might be %d\n", i, f[i]);
    } 
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Provide your name\n");
        return 0;
    }

    vuln(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

So far, using gdb, I can get a segmentation fault when I push the size of the input to 1026. That is, `run $(python -c "print('A'*1026)")`.

However, no matter how much I increase the 1026, the `$eip` is always `0x8049323`. I have looked long and hard online for any similar problem, but I have failed to find any.

I am aware there's a similar question with similar code, but the answer doesn't address my problem.

EDIT: For reference, yes, the x41's do reach in, they just never make it all the way to $eip.

[image]

Also, these are the info reg's before and after the input is strcpy-ed in.

**Before**: 
[image]

**After**
[image]

And the address of the buf variable is 0xffffd230 before and after. And the address of read_secret() is 0x80491c2.

Comment: How are you compiling your program? You should be using `-fno-stack-protector` and (in my case) `-m32`. Have you tried stepping through your program with GDB? Compile with a `-g` flag and try running it through `gdb a.out`

Comment: @VeridianDynamics This is exactly how I'm compiling it. Exactly the same as you. And your suggestion sadly doesn't address my question.

Comment: It wasn't an answer. I'm using the comments in SO to gather more information since your original question was not specific enough. A common root cause of a failure in learning buffer overflow attack is using modern gcc without turning off security flags.

Since you cannot even get the x414141 address from passing in A, that means you're not overflowing your buffer at all. 

It's possible you're not moving in the right location on the stack. What are the addresses of your `buf` variable and your function?

Comment: Try `-fno-PIC -fno-PIE -no-pie` compile options.

Comment: @VeridianDynamics Apologies, I just edited the question to provide more detail. So, yes, the x41's do make it in, just not far enough to hit the $eip. So I presume the buffer is indeed overflowing here since x41's appear in the seg fault. The address of the buf is 0xffffd230 before and after. The address of read_secret() is 0x80491c2.

Comment: @user617040 I'm new to this too, I spent about 1-2 hours trying to overwrite `eip`. I recommend using a simpler example. I was seeing that `n` was being overwritten and seg faulting on the `fib` function because of that. My current code is overwriting `eip` using a simpler version of your program. But whenever I get the write address (`0x08045456`) it jumps to a new address that causes an invalid memory error. I don't know why it jumps, but I'm definitely able to confirm `eip` is changing since I can see x41 slowly enter it as I increase the number of `A`s passed in.

Comment: @VeridianDynamics Thanks for spending such time on this! I managed to finally get to $eip on my program by writing legal addresses in the buffer instead followed by 'A's.

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind answering your own question with a simple version of your program, the compilation step, and the python script for the overflow? You don't have to do that, but it may help others in the future (and I'd like to give it a try tonight!)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that inside the program there comes a point where the program attempts to print f[i]'s. These are overwritten by the buffer to illegal addresses (i.e. 0x41414141).

What I instead did is that I picked an address from 'info reg' (the $ebp) worked for me, and inserted that address multiple times until I hit the $eip. Essentially, you want to pick a LEGAL address here.

Then, I'd reduce the number of times the address I picked is repeated and put a 'AAAA' instead to see where the $eip is. Once I find the $eip, I put the address of the function I want to execute there instead.